# I'm trying to install -r requirements.txt from a flask app from github

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/felipeveraloza/Desktop/flask-aws-tutorial/flask-aws/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/_d/tpx546q90svbs7y84bgplfpm0000gn/T/pip-install-qql4powj/distribute/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_d/tpx546q90svbs7y84bgplfpm0000gn/T/pip-install-qql4powj/distribute/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/_d/tpx546q90svbs7y84bgplfpm0000gn/T/pip-install-qql4powj/distribute/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /private/var/folders/_d/tpx546q90svbs7y84bgplfpm0000gn/T/pip-install-qql4powj/distribute/
Complete output (10 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/_d/tpx546q90svbs7y84bgplfpm0000gn/T/pip-install-qql4powj/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
  File "/private/var/folders/_d/tpx546q90svbs7y84bgplfpm0000gn/T/pip-install-qql4powj/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/private/var/folders/_d/tpx546q90svbs7y84bgplfpm0000gn/T/pip-install-qql4powj/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 103
    except ValueError, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It looks like a syntax error.

it should be "except ValueError as e". try replacing the comma with a "as"

Comment: `except ValueError, e` is valid Python 2 syntax, but not for Python 3.  Is there a Python 3 specific version of the package you're trying to install?

Comment: I use python 3.7 and I am trying to do this: github.com/inkjet/flask-aws-tutorial but I get stuck on the requirements install par

Comment: for starters Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0 supports up to Python 3.4. Most likely you are trying to install many things that are not compatible with your current version of python. The requirements.txt file is from May of 2015. You likely would want to start in a different place or you may want to use a previous version of python but you'd want to check what requirements are compatible with first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: what version of python are you using and what are you trying to install...? need more details

Comment: I use python 3.7 and I am trying to do this: https://github.com/inkjet/flask-aws-tutorial but I get stuck on the requirements install part.

Comment: What is your OS (windows, Mac...) ?

Comment: Mac running Catalina

Comment: Can you try ``` $ pip3 install -r requirements.txt```

Answer (score 0):

I would specify the version of Pip you are using. Mac is defaulted to python 2.7... in your case i would run the command as "pip3" so in your case...

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```